# Dart Hive use Set causing unknown type error

Tags: flutter, dart

i would like to use `set` with hive. But it seems causing error: `Unhandled Exception: HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: _CompactLinkedHashSet<int>. Did you forget to register an adapter?`

```
    final Box box = Hive.box("NumberBox");
    box.put("uniqueIds", <int>{});

    var setList = box.get("uniqueIds");
    setList.add(1);
    setList.add(2);
    setList.add(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Hive documentation](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/custom-objects/type_adapters):

> Hive supports all primitive types, `List`, `Map`, `DateTime` and `Uint8List`. If you want to store other objects, you have to register a `TypeAdapter` which converts the object from and to binary form.

`Set` is not supported out of the box, so you would need to handle that separately.  The simplest way would be to convert your `Set` to a `List` when writing to the box, and convert that `List` to a `Set` when you read it back.